# Pipelined function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have created a pipelined function in Oracle. I need to use this function to get a column value in table format; for that I have written this query:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE (
               parse_comma_delimited(
                                      ( SELECT SOURCE_COLUMNS 
                                          FROM BW_SUPERMERGE_RULES 
                                         WHERE RULE_NAME = 'SQL2CUB' 
                                      ), ',')
                                    )
               );
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Can any one suggest me to how to fix this?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 3):

I think your parenthesis is not properly matched, I've edited the code

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE (parse_comma_delimited (SELECT SOURCE_COLUMNS 
                                     FROM BW_SUPERMERGE_RULES 
                                     WHERE RULE_NAME = 'SQL2CUB', ','));
```

Basically these kind of errors are for syntax.

Comment: But iam still getting error like"ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query"

Comment: Check with the above code again, i modified it and let me know for any other concerns

Comment: i got this error "14551. 00000 -  "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query "
*Cause:    DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update
           cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.
*Action:   Ensure that the offending DML operation is not performed or
           use an autonomous transaction to perform the DML operation within
           the query or PDML slave."

Comment: Your parce_comma_delimited() function probably does some kind of insert / update (perhaps into a temporary table?), and this is not allowed in a SELECT. That's what Oracle is trying to tell you with the ORA-14551.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work; if your function parse_comma_delimited is correct.

```
    SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE (
    parse_comma_delimited(
    ( SELECT SOURCE_COLUMNS  
        FROM BW_SUPERMERGE_RULES  
       WHERE RULE_NAME = 'SQL2CUB' 
    ), ',')
   );
```

Comment: Could you please try to get rid of all the dude's in your answers? Personally, I find these *very* irritating.